# Не добавляются картинки к постам. Проект на django

Tags: python, django

Я создал проект на django. Мини соцсеть. Все работало, но сейчас обнаружил баг. Помогите разобраться. Мой проект это соц сеть, где авторы добавиляют свои посты, комментируют посты друг друга, и подписываются друг на друга. И все было нормально, но сейчас я обнаружил, что при создании нового поста не добавляется картинка. Пост создаётся без нее. А добавить ее можно к этому посту только путем редактирования. Создал пост картинка не добавилась, отредактировал тогда добавилась. Все посмотрел, но причины не нашел. Подскажите кто как думает, в чем проблема? Нужный код прикреплю, говорите, что нужно. Спасибо!

```
@login_required
def new_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'new_post.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def post_edit(request, username, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, author__username=username)
    if post.author != request.user:
        return redirect('post', username=post.author.username, post_id=post_id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=post)
    #form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(
                'post',
                username=request.user.username,
                post_id=post_id
                )
    return render(request, 'new_post.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})
```

Comment: В post_edit используется request.FILES, а в new_post не используется, наверное дело в этом?

Comment: Точно!) Спасибо